# "XXX can't be opened. You should move it to trash." for flash projector applications on mac os sierra

Tags: macos, adobe-flash, code-signing, gatekeeper

We are experiencing a problem with flash projector .app executables that we build. When the app is downloaded from the internet on OSX sierra the message "**XXX can't be opened. You should move it to trash.**" is thrown. 
[image]

Clicking on the help icon next to it additionally displays the info:

> The app’s authorization has been revoked There may be a problem with
>   this app. Although the app was signed by an identified developer, the
>   certificate for the app has been revoked, and it cannot be opened.

The same app copied through a pen drive works fine. The same app downloaded over internet in other OSX versions runs fine.

We have tried options like Settings>Security > allow apps downloaded from: Anywhere in the OSX Gatekeeper settings. The application being a app published by Flash CS6 is not something that we sign ourselves. I have also read elsewhere that the Flash Player certificate was revoked by apple earlier due to a breach. But updating the Flash software with latest patches has not made a difference.

Has anyone else experienced this issue. Any workarounds/advise?
Thanks!

Answer (score 54):

This is actually a macOS Gatekeeper issue try these steps:

To resolute Gatekeeper issues on macOS Sierra you might have to partially or completely disable Gatekeeper checks.

**Option I**
For a certain application run in Terminal:

```
sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine /Applications/[LockedApp].app
```

**Option II**
To disable checks globally run in Terminal:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

Comment: Option II worked for me

Comment: In my case, Option II did not have any effect. it still would prohibit it to open. But opening it with the terminal did work. The app was in a folder, copied the whole thing from the DMG (Adobe CS5 old Ps update). Then ran the command on the folder first, it asked for password, after entering it tried opening the file with the terminal and it worked.

Comment: Option I worked for me

Comment: option II worked. Now I can open the file. What a bug!!!

Comment: Except Option II totally disables Gatekeeper. It's not an ideal solution. I had issues at one point that required me to turn it off temporarily, but I didn't LEAVE it off. Don't recommend that you do, either.

Comment: This didn't work for me

Comment: Even simpler, try `xattr -cr /path/to/application.app`. (From [osxdaily.com](http://osxdaily.com/2019/02/13/fix-app-damaged-cant-be-opened-trash-error-mac).)

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a permissions issue. If so, here's how to fix it:

1. Open Terminal and type the following command, but don't press enter: `sudo chmod +x`
2. Be sure to type a space after the `x`.
3. Then, navigate to the application in the Finder.
4. Right-click it and choose "Show package contents."
5. Navigate to Contents/MacOS
6. Usually there's just one file; if so, select it. Otherwise, find the one that's most like the application's name, with no extension.
7. Click the file and drag it to the Terminal window.
8. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd> and authenticate with an admin password.

Comment: Thanks for the permissions fix info. Indeed the file does run after running chmod so it is a permissions issue. My problem however is that the .app has to be provided to users for download over the internet. We can't expect our users to follow these steps to be able to run the app. Any advise on how the file can be runnable on download.

Comment: If you simply zip it, that should do the problem. Right click the app and select "Compress" or "Create Archive" (depending on macOS version), and upload the resulting zip file.

Comment: How are users downloading the file? As a bare app, or as a disk image containing the app? Are you signing the disk image itself? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824815/how-to-add-codesigning-to-dmg-file-in-mac